# Possible even integer values of $y$ under a system of quadratic and linear equations

Tags: inequality, quadratics

> If $$25(9x^2+y^2)+9z^2-15(5xy+yz+3zx)=0$$ and $$x+y+z=18$$ then possible even integral values of ($y$) less than $15$ are: ?

My attempt:
I manipulated the given equation in this form
$$(15x)^2+(5y)^2+(3z)^2-(15x)(5y)-(5y)(3z)-(15x)(3z)$$
which is of the form
 $$a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca$$ but what should I do after this? Any hints?

Comment: @normal sorry,but I run this site from smartphone and no mathjax is available here ...that's why I do not use it..sorry for the inconvenience..

Comment: I sometimes edit posts from my smartphone to correct the formatting: it's possible to enter `$a^2+b^2+c^2$` and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$2(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca)=\sum(a-b)^2$$

Now for real $x, x^2\ge0$

So what if $a-b,b-c,c-a$ are real?

Comment: Thnx..I got the answer 6 that is ...strange how little was left after the first step

Comment: @Freelancer, You actually did the hard work:)